# How to group multiple arrays into one, then flatten and find distinct items

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Having a dataframe like below:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, Seq("USD", "CAD")),
  (2, Seq("AUD", "YEN", "USD")),
  (2, Seq("GBP", "AUD", "YEN")),
  (3, Seq("BRL", "AUS", "BND","BOB","BWP")),
  (3, Seq("XAF", "CLP", "BRL")),
  (3, Seq("XAF", "CNY", "KMF","CSK","EGP")
  )
).toDF("ACC", "CCY")

+---+-------------------------+
|ACC|CCY                      |
+---+-------------------------+
|1  |[USD, CAD]               |
|2  |[AUD, YEN, USD]          |
|2  |[GBP, AUD, YEN]          |
|3  |[BRL, AUS, BND, BOB, BWP]|
|3  |[XAF, CLP, BRL]          |
|3  |[XAF, CNY, KMF, CSK, EGP]|
+---+-------------------------+
```

This has to be transformed as below by removing the duplicates too.

**Spark Version = 2.0
Scala Version = 2.10**

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|ACC|CCY                                                    |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[USD,CAD]                                              |
|2  |[AUD,YEN,USD,GBP]                                      |
|3  |[BRL,AUS,BND,BOB,BWP,XAF,CLP,CNY,KMF,CSK,EGP]          |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried grouping by ACC column and aggregating the CCY but not sure where to go from there.

Can this be done without using UDF? If NO, then how would I go about this using UDF?
Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next code should return the expected results:

```
    import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
    val df = Seq(
      (1, Seq("USD", "CAD")),
      (2, Seq("AUD", "YEN", "USD")),
      (2, Seq("GBP", "AUD", "YEN")),
      (3, Seq("BRL", "AUS", "BND", "BOB", "BWP")),
      (3, Seq("XAF", "CLP", "BRL")),
      (3, Seq("XAF", "CNY", "KMF", "CSK", "EGP")
      )
    ).toDF("ACC", "CCY")

    val castToArray = udf((ccy: WrappedArray[WrappedArray[String]]) => ccy.flatten.distinct.toArray)

    val df2 = df.groupBy($"ACC")
      .agg(collect_list($"CCY").as("CCY"))
      .withColumn("CCY", castToArray($"CCY"))
        .show(false)
```

First I use groupBy("ACC") then with the aggregate collect_list all arrays are concentrated into one. Next, inside the udf function values of CCY are being unwrapped and the results are flattened.

Output:

```
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|ACC|CCY                                                    |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[USD, CAD]                                             |
|3  |[BRL, AUS, BND, BOB, BWP, XAF, CLP, CNY, KMF, CSK, EGP]|
|2  |[AUD, YEN, USD, GBP]                                   |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Good luck

**UPDATE:**

In Spark >= 2.4 you can use the build-in flatten and array_distinct functions and avoid the usage of udf:

```
df.groupBy($"ACC")
          .agg(collect_list($"CCY").as("CCY"))
          .select($"ACC", array_distinct(flatten($"CCY")).as("CCY"))
          .show(false)

//Output
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+ 
|ACC|CCY                                                    | 
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+ 
|1  |[USD, CAD]                                             | 
|3  |[BRL, AUS, BND, BOB, BWP, XAF, CLP, CNY, KMF, CSK, EGP]| 
|2  |[AUD, YEN, USD, GBP]                                   | 
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @@Alexandros!!. I will wait for people to answer without UDF for sometime and will then accept your answer :)

Comment: sure @1pluszara best luck!