# columns value in order

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this DataFrame bellow:

```
Ref °     | indice_1 | Indice_2      | rank_1    |   rank_2   |  echelon_from     |    section_from      |      echelon_to    |  section_to 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
70574931  |   19     |   37.1        |  32       |    62      |  ["10032,20032"]  |   ["11/12","13"]     |      ["40062"]     |   ["14A"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
70574931  |   18     |   36          |  32       |    62      |     ["20032"]     |      ["13"]          |    ["30062,40062"] |  ["14,14A"]
```

I want concatenate the lines that have the same Ref° number, to concatenate echelon_from values, section_from values, echelon_to values and section_to values with duplicates there values, like in example bellow, and without touch the rest of the columns.

```
Ref °     | Indice_1 | Indice_2      | rank_1    |   rank_2   |  echelon_from     |    section_from      |      echelon_to    |  section_to  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
70574931  |   19     |   37.1        |  32       |    62      |  ["10032,20032"]  |   ["11/12","13"]     |     ["30062,40062"] |  ["14,14A"]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
70574931  |   18     |   36          |  32       |    62      |  ["10032,20032"]  |   ["11/12","13"]     |    ["30062,40062"] |  ["14,14A"]
```

Some columns values in my original Dataframe are duplicates, I shouldn't touch them, I should keep there values to keep the same line numer of my DataFrame.
Someone can help me please how can I do it ?

Thank you!

Comment: @Ben.T Ref ° , Indice_1, Indice_2 , rank_1 and rank_2 are String
 Echelon_from ,Section_from  , Echelon_to and  Section_to are Array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group multiple arrays into one, then flatten and find distinct items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802633/how-to-group-multiple-arrays-into-one-then-flatten-and-find-distinct-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways of doing this. One way is to explode all the given lists and collect them back again as a set.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

lists_to_concat = ['echelon_from', 'section_from', 'echelon_to', 'section_to']
columns_not_to_concat = [c for c in df.columns if c not in lists_to_concat]

for c in lists_to_concat:
    df = df.withColumn(c, F.explode(c))

df = (
    df
    .groupBy(*columns_not_to_concat)
    .agg(
        *[F.collect_set(c).alias(c) for c in lists_to_concat]
    )
)
```

Another more elegant way is to use `flatten()`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

lists_to_concat = ['echelon_from', 'section_from', 'echelon_to', 'section_to']
for c in lists_to_concat:
    df = df.withColumn(c, F.flatten(c))
```

References:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten

Comment: I've updated the answer. The one before didn't work because I was exploding multiple columns in one `.select()` statement. Above should work.